# Slow execution of Symfony project locally

Tags: windows, symfony, netbeans, wampserver

I have this problem for quite a long time but it is getting slower and slower to display a simple page of my Symfony 2 project.

This is my development environment:

- Wampserver 2.2 with PHP 5.3.13, MySQL 5.5.24 and Apache 2.2.22
- Symfony 2.7
- Netbeans 8.1

I am really not sure it comes from Symfony though it is more obvious with a symfony project (4-5 minutes to display a page).

Even calling phpmyadmin from the wampserver is long.

No problem with the memory, the CPU or the disk. Using the resources manager to check, everything seems to be fine.

Those are Apache logs. I have kilometers of :

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 90 seconds exceeded in  C:\wamp\www\MyProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php on line 5270, referer:  http://localhost/MyProject/web/app_dev.php/myURL?init
>   [Thu May 12 14:11:28 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:,  referer: http://localhost/MyProject/web/app_dev.php/myURL?init
>   [Thu May 12 14:11:28 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. Monolog\Handler\AbstractHandler->__destruct()  C:\wamp\www\MyProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php:0, referer:   http://localhost/MyProject/web/app_dev.php/myURL?init
>   [Thu May 12 14:11:30 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 90 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\MyProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php on line 5270, referer: http://localhost/MyProject/web/app_dev.php/myURL?init
>       [Thu May 12 14:11:30 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/MyProject/web/app_dev.php/myURL?init
>       [Thu May 12 14:11:30 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. Monolog\Handler\AbstractHandler->__destruct() C:\wamp\www\MyProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php:0, referer: http://localhost/MyProject/web/app_dev.php/myURL?init
>       [Thu May 12 14:11:32 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 90 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\MyProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php on line 5270, referer: http://localhost/MyProject/web/app_dev.php/myURL?init
>       [Thu May 12 14:11:32 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/MyProject/web/app_dev.php/myURL?init
>       [Thu May 12 14:11:32 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. Monolog\Handler\AbstractHandler->__destruct() C:\wamp\www\MyProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php:0, referer: http://localhost/MyProject/web/app_dev.php/myURL?init
>       [Thu May 12 14:13:04 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 90 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\MyProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php on line 5270, referer: http://localhost/MyProject/web/app_dev.php/myURL?init

Does anybody Have any idea of what i can do... I already reinstalled several time my software but it does not change anything

Thanks for the ideas and any help.

Comment: Do you have XDebug enabled?

Comment: absolutly.. to use debug with Netbeans

Comment: Try to disable XDebug (completely) and check if it gets better. It shouldn't slow down Symfony so much, but its worth trying.

Comment: Indeed it is slow but a lot less...22 second to display the page and no more "Maximum time of 90 seconds exceeded...what I can do to debug and make it work so ?

Comment: Now, when you can successfully render a Symfony page, I would check what took so much time in Symfony's profiler.

Comment: In symfony profiler I have a render time at 3000 ms or 6000 ms but in reality it is twice as long...at least.  By the way, what are block calls ?

Comment: You can post your xdebug answer... I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basing on comments under question, we came to the answer that the main reason is XDebug which usually has significant impact on PHP performance.

You wrote in your command that Symfony's profiler now shows 3-6 seconds, but in practice it takes a lot more. That means, that PHP itself is probably not the only problem.

I would suggest to look into browser's developer tools (Firebug etc, depending on the browser you use) and check timeline in Network tab. Maybe it will give you further information where to look for the reason.

For my local computer it usually takes PHP about a second (on dev env; and depending on cache state and what page is it) to execute Symfony.

Comment: I give url for xdebug versions depending on PHP version https://xdebug.org/files/

Comment: Ive been developign with this xdubug thing more than 5 years now. Almost made me switch to Linux. Words cant describe how much i thank you @Jakub !!

Answer (score 5):

What I have done to speed up symfony execution time in dev mode on my local machine:

1. Install PHP 7.*, it really improves performance.
2. Enabled Opcache PHP extension bundled with PHP
3. Set `realpath_cache_size` to `4048k`
4. Install redis and enable metadata cache in doctrine config. Bear in mind each time you add/change entity files you have to clear redis cache manually. It worth it as it increases load time by about 70-100ms in dev mode.
5. Execute `composer dump-autoload --optimize` to create class map.

I have had around 700-1000ms load time in dev mode before optimization and now it's 250-350.

Of course, numbers will be differrent on your machine.

Comment: Sorry I cannot do that... I understand what you say and I am sure you are right but I work in a big firm and I do not decide the versions of PHP or whatever. It is national.

Comment: But I will remember what You have just said in twenty years when we are PHP 7